# HAAR Cascade type of images for recognising cars

Tags: opencv, haar-classifier

I want to write a python script to highlight cars in a picture (with a reactangle (OPENCV)).
I'm going to make a HAAR Cascade, but I'm a bit stuck. I read a lot about it, and I have some concerns.

I'm planning on using pictures of cars without a background (no road or anything like that) as my **positive images**.
As **negative images** I would use empty roads.

Also I'd like to know how many pictures should I get? On forums I've read that I would need 1000 **positive** and 10 000 **negative** pictures.

Is my thought process correct?

Comment: since you cant have "empty" regions in a n image, your positive images will always have some kind of background. This means your positive images now probably would have a black or a white background, which introduces features to your training (to every sample) which are likely not relevant for the actual detection task. So I would suggest to use real images from cars with real background OR use the ceratesamples tool to ADD different background to your "without background" sample.

Comment: I think HAAR car detection will only be successful if you limit to samples of a single perspective. just like there is a different detector for front-faces and for side-faces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HAAR cascade is old technology (before convolutional neural networks), nowadays there are more advanced techniques to solve car detection problems. The way you are approaching the problem is correct, the problem is data quality can greatly influence results. I did a demo using a more advanced algorithm if you want to check (it comes with pre-trained models).

[Car detection using YOLO V3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cVC7KXcxE04&t=81s)